# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" when running Docker on linux, even with find command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let's say I've got a simple Dockerfile to start my Python app:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install poetry

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install uvicorn -y
RUN apt-get clean -y

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY * ./

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "3800"]
```

One of the things I install here is `uvicorn`. In fact, it is installed twice: with `apt-get` and with `pip`, because it is in `requirements.txt`. But when I start this container, it says that there are no `uvicorn` binary: `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`.

I thought that this might be an issue with `uvicorn` being installed outside of PATH. So, I added a `find` instruction:

```
RUN find / -name uvicorn
```

But it fails as well, as if the system didn't have it installed:

```
Step 10/11 : RUN find / -name "uvicorn"
 ---> Running in fdf4a53a75cd
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't my container start binaries which are definitely there?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I changed

```
COPY * ./
```

to

```
COPY . ./
```

and now everything is working fine. I'd be happy if somebody could explain why is it so.